# Strategy for creating pivot tables that collapse with large data sets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I'm new to the community and I only recently started to use Python and more specifically Pandas.

The data set I have I would like the columns to be the date.  For each Date I would like to have a customer list that then breaks down to more specific row elements.  Everything would be rolled up by an order number, so a distinct count on an order number because sometimes a client purchases more than 1 item. In excel I create a pivot table and process it by distinct order.  Then I sort each row element by the distinct count of the order number.  I collapse each row down until I just have the client name.  If I click to expand the cell then I see each row element.

So my question:  If I'm pulling in these huge data sets as a dataframe can I pull in xlsx in as an array?  I know it will strip the values, so I would have to set the datetime as a datetime64 element.  I've been trying to reshape the array around the date being column, and the rows I want but so far I haven't had luck.  I have tried to use pivot_table and groupby with some success but I wasn't able to move the date to the column.

Summary:  Overall what I'm looking to know is am I going down the wrong rabbit hole together?  I'm looking to basically create a collapsible pivot table with specific color parameters for the table as well so that the current spreadsheet will look identical to the one I'm automating.

I really appreciate any help, as I said I'm brand new to Pandas so direction is key.  If I know I'm onto the "best" way of dealing with the export to excel after I've imported and modified the spreadsheet.  I get a single sheet of raw data kicked out in .xlsx form.  Thanks again!

Comment: if you post your code and some sample dataset it will be easy to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write the code.  I've tried groupby, and pivot tables.  What I'm looking to do is #1.  Export a pivot table from a CSV to an Excel spreadsheet.  #2 Create rows that can be collapsed.  So that when the spreadsheet opens I can get the plus sign that allows me to dig down into each row.  The value would be a distinct number and the column would be the date.  I've tried in Pandas but can only get the pivot table to show as a static table.  I'm not sure if Pandas is the wrong answer and I should maybe be using openpyxl instead but I haven't had luck with it yet either.  Thanks!

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar to this but with Linux instead of windows.  I'm looking for real pivot tables not just a static pivot table.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128206/how-to-insert-a-real-pivot-table-in-a-excel-sheet-with-python