# Write pivot table in Excel

Tags: python, excel

Is there a python library that supports writing a pivot table in Excel? For example, I usually use xlwt or [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html), but it seems xlwt doesn't support it and OpenPyXL only supports reading pivot tables: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html.

What would be the suggested way to do this?

Comment: Should (fingers crossed) be doable with `win32com`, if by "write" a pivot table you mean create a pivot table from scratch.

Comment: @BigBen yea, from scratch, though I don't have a problem creating all the data let's say in tab1. The pivot would be 'from scratch in tab2' if that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128206/how-to-insert-a-real-pivot-table-in-a-excel-sheet-with-python

Comment: @jfaccioni oh cool thanks for the tip, I'll test that out! https://www.yinglinglow.com/blog/2018/04/29/xlwings-pivot-table